# Azure Devops Branches tab not displaying anything in the build pipelines

Tags: azure-devops

Azure Devops Branches tab not displaying anything in the build pipelines .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgPIw.png)

Comment: Hi, This issue seems be fixed now. You can check it again.

Answer (score 0):

What access do you have on your org or project?

Usually for Basic Access, there might be a blocked permission for your account that denies your access to see branches.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been reported to Azure DevOps product team, please track it: [Pipeline Branches tab missing branches](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1089183/pipeline-branches-tab-missing-branches.html)